# how to download a file in app made by intel xdk?

Tags: download, intel

how to download a file in app made by intel xdk something like android internal download manager ?
how can I use cordova file transfer ? can you tell me in details please ?

Beginner

Answer (score 0):

when you build the apk in Andoird, iOS or crosswalk when the message of the build was successful apear you may press download build to get the file or send to your mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/), for more guidance, please see
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html